# matplotlib bar plot for logarithmic y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I try to make a bar plot for a logarithmic y axis. Unfortunately, there are no bars anymore, if I set the y-axis to be logarithmic. What can I do to achieve this? Is there a possibility to set the reference point (default seems to be zero) in the bar-function?

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N=1000
sample=np.random.random_integers(1,10,N)
hist,bins=np.histogram(sample)


fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5),nrows=1,ncols=2,sharex=True,sharey=False)
ax[1].set_yscale("log")
ax[0].bar(bins[:-1],1.*hist/N,np.diff(bins))
ax[1].bar(bins[:-1],1.*hist/N,np.diff(bins))

plt.show()
```

The output:
[image: linear and log y axis]

How to make the bars in the right panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating maptlotlib. Works for me with version 1.4.2.

[image]

Comment: hmm.. I have the version 1.3.1 of matplotlib. Actually, I use python on a server by a ssh connection. I am afraid I don't have the rights to update.

Comment: Use `virtualenv` or `pip install --user`.

Comment: thx! but in the end this worked: `ax[1].bar(bins[:-1],1.*hist/N,np.diff(bins),log=True)`

Comment: @Andy I'm glad you've sorted your problem out!  Please post that comment as an answer for people who may run into the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the version 1.3.1 of matplotlib, the following solved my problem:

```
ax[1].bar(bins[:-1],1.*hist/N,np.diff(bins),log=True)
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to help people understand why this is the best solution or how it works etc, rather than leave it at a single line of code.